# What am I doing wrong with converting this map to and from JSON?

Tags: json, go

I'm trying to store a map with struct key in a file, so I'm converting it to and from JSON.  But the map that I end up with has only a single entry with a zero key, and the last value from the original map.  (My sample code here doesn't do the file I/O.)

I've looked at various similar examples that seem to work, and I can't see where I've gone wrong.

```
import (
    "encoding/json"
    "errors"
    "fmt"
)

type XY struct {
    X int
    Y int
}

func (xy XY) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("{X:%v, Y:%v}", xy.X, xy.Y)
}
func (xy XY) MarshalText() ([]byte, error) {
    text := []byte(fmt.Sprintf("%d,%d", xy.X, xy.Y))
    fmt.Printf("Marshalled %v to %s\n", xy, text)
    return text, nil
}
func (xy XY) UnmarshalText(p []byte) error {
    n, err := fmt.Sscanf(string(p), "%d,%d", &xy.X, &xy.Y)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    } else if n != 2 {
        return errors.New("Cannot parse as XY: '" + string(p) + "'")
    }
    fmt.Printf("Unmarshalled %s to %v\n", p, xy)
    return nil
}

type XYMap = map[XY]string

func loadXY(data []byte, xymap XYMap) error {
    err := json.Unmarshal(data, &xymap)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("unmarshal error:", err)
    }
    return err
}

func main() {
    xymap := make(XYMap)
    xymap[XY{1,2}] = "one two"
    xymap[XY{3,4}] = "three four"
    bytes, err := json.Marshal(xymap)
    fmt.Printf("xymap=%v  \nbytes=%s  err=%v\n", xymap, bytes, err)
    newxymap := make(XYMap)
    loadXY(bytes, newxymap)
    fmt.Printf("newxymap=%v\n", newxymap)
}
```

Output:

```
Marshalled {X:1, Y:2} to 1,2
Marshalled {X:3, Y:4} to 3,4
xymap=map[{X:1, Y:2}:one two {X:3, Y:4}:three four]  
bytes={"1,2":"one two","3,4":"three four"}  err=<nil>
Unmarshalled 1,2 to {X:1, Y:2}
Unmarshalled 3,4 to {X:3, Y:4}
newxymap=map[{X:0, Y:0}:three four]
```

Comment: Declare the unmarshal function on the pointer receiver: `func (xy *XY) UnmarshalText(p []byte) error { ... }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use a pointer receiver for unmarshal text.

```
func (xy *XY) UnmarshalText(p []byte) error {
 ...
}
```

With your current version, `UnmarshalText` does not modify the receiver, and the map ends up getting empty keys.

Comment: Excellent -- that solved it.  Thank you for your quick and accurate reply.  I was fooled by the fact that UnmarshalText puts the values in `&xy.X` and `&xy.Y` -- the `&` made me think that I had done enough indirection.  In fact those can be written as `&(xy.X)` which makes it clear that it's NOT `(&x).X`.